# Keras .fit giving better performance than manual Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to Tensorflow and Keras. To get started, I followed the https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced tutorial. I'm now adapting it to train on CIFAR10 instead of MNIST dataset. I recreated this model https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/ and I'm trying to run it in my own codebase.

Logically, if the model, batch size and optimizer are all the same, then the two should perform identically, but they don't. I thought it might be that I'm making a mistake in preparing the data. So I copied the model.fit function from the keras code into my script, and it still performs better. Using .fit gives me around 75% accuracy in 25 epochs, while with the manual method it takes around 60 epochs. With .fit I also achieve slightly better max accuracy.

What I want to know is: Is .fit doing something behind the scenes that's optimizing training? What do I need to add to my code to get the same performance? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Main code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import msvcrt
from Plotter import Plotter


#########################Configuration Settings#############################

BatchSize = 32
ModelName = "CifarModel"

############################################################################


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

print("x_train",x_train.shape)
print("y_train",y_train.shape)
print("x_test",x_test.shape)
print("y_test",y_test.shape)

x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)



train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (x_train, y_train)).batch(BatchSize)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test)).batch(BatchSize)


loss_object = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001,decay=1e-6)

# Create an instance of the model
model = ModelManager.loadModel(ModelName,10)


train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='test_accuracy')



########### Using this function I achieve better results ##################

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=BatchSize,
              epochs=100,
              validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
              shuffle=True,
              verbose=2)

############################################################################

########### Using the below code I achieve worse results ##################

@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(images, training=True)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(labels, predictions)

@tf.function
def test_step(images, labels):
  predictions = model(images, training=False)
  t_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

  test_loss(t_loss)
  test_accuracy(labels, predictions)

epoch = 0
InterruptLoop = False
while InterruptLoop == False:
  #Shuffle training data
  train_ds.shuffle(1000)
  epoch = epoch + 1
  # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
  train_loss.reset_states()
  train_accuracy.reset_states()
  test_loss.reset_states()
  test_accuracy.reset_states()

  for images, labels in train_ds:
    train_step(images, labels)

  for test_images, test_labels in test_ds:
    test_step(test_images, test_labels)

  test_accuracy = test_accuracy.result() * 100
  train_accuracy = train_accuracy.result() * 100

  #Print update to console
  template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}, Test Loss: {}, Test Accuracy: {}'
  print(template.format(epoch,
                        train_loss.result(),
                        train_accuracy ,
                        test_loss.result(),
                        test_accuracy))

  # Check if keyboard pressed
  while msvcrt.kbhit():
    char = str(msvcrt.getch())
    if char == "b'q'":
      InterruptLoop = True
      print("Stopping loop")
```

The model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class ModelData(Model):
  def __init__(self,NumberOfOutputs):
    super(ModelData, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(32,32,3))
    self.conv2 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.maxpooling1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    self.dropout1 = Dropout(0.25)
    ############################
    self.conv3 = Conv2D(64,3,activation='relu',padding='same')
    self.conv4 = Conv2D(64,3,activation='relu')
    self.maxpooling2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    self.dropout2 = Dropout(0.25)
    ############################
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')
    self.dropout3 = Dropout(0.5)
    self.d2 = Dense(NumberOfOutputs,activation='softmax')

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.maxpooling1(x)
    x = self.dropout1(x)
    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.conv4(x)
    x = self.maxpooling2(x)
    x = self.dropout2(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    x = self.dropout3(x)
    x = self.d2(x)
    return x
```

Comment: I haven't used [CategoricalAccuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/CategoricalAccuracy), but I am quite certain that it is not the same as [Accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy). If that is the case, than you're trying to compare the results using 2 different metrics.

Comment: I'm not sure about something that can be hidden within the fit method of keras, but I think that the difference rises by the different shuffles. You can try to use keras method train_on_batch ensuring that the batch is the same for both keras and tf. 
A last thing: what about the asymptotic behavior of  the two model? What happen after 100 or 200 epochs? In my opinion the benchmark should be evaluated after a large number of epochs, in order to delete any inner fluctuation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile (under metrics) the string 'accuracy' will be converted to the most fitting metric. I changed the string to 'CategoricalAccuracy' to be sure and got the exact same result. .fit still just performs better.

Comment: I turned off shuffling for both but it made no difference. Using train_on_batch gives the same result as 'fit' method, even though everything else is the same as manual method. Asymptotically: They plateau around the same value (78-80% which is to be expected for this model) although fit method reaches it in +-60 epochs and manual method only at around 130. They will eventually plateau to nearly the same value, but using fit always gets it closer in less epochs. Using Adam with manual method and too many parameters can cause instability, but fit with the same settings never becomes unstable.

Comment: By chance, did you ever figure out why there is a discrepancy between model.fit( ) and the manual method? I am encountering a similar issue with my dataset, and I'm not sure why. I haven't tried turning off shuffling, but you said it didn't do anything so I suspect something else is at play.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but I never solved this mystery. You can try to turn off shuffling to see if it solves your problem but it didn't do much for me. I use PyTorch these days as it gives much more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question already has an answer, but I faced the same problem and the solution seemed to be something different, that's not specified in the documentation.

I copy & paste here the answer (and the relative link) I found on GitHub, which solved the issue in my case:

> The problem is caused by broadcasting in your loss function in the
> custom loop. Make sure that the dimensions of predictions and label is
> equal. At the moment (for MAE) they are [128,1] and [128]. Just make
> use of tf.squeeze or tf.expand_dims.

Link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28394

Basic translation: when computing the loss, always be sure of the tensors' shapes.

Comment: Accepting this as answer, since I mentioned in the comment thread that shuffling did not change the outcome.
Thank you for your answer and the posted link!

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments, for the **benefit of the Community**.

On the same `Dataset`, the Accuracy can differ when using `Keras Model.fit` with that of the `Model` built using `Tensorflow` mainly if the Data is shuffled because, when we shuffle the Data, the Split of Data between Training and Testing (or Validation) will be different resulting in different Train and Test Data in both the cases (Keras and Tensorflow).

If we want to observe the similar results on the Same Dataset and with similar Architecture in `Keras` and in `Tensorflow`, we can `Turn off Shuffling the Data`.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!